# Cannot get JAXBContext?

Tags: java, jaxb

In my java project i have a jar that i generated with some classes. I am able to instantiate the instance of the class that is in my jar:

```
Alert a = new Alert();
```

But wen i try to do this:

```
JAXBContext context  = JAXBContext.newInstance(Alert.class);
```

I get run time exception like this:

> java.lang.InternalError: 
>   Error occured while invoking reflection on target classes. Make sure all referenced classes are on classpath: interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter 
>   Exception: null

Any idea what could be the issue?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show `Alert` class? The message is clear, some class is missing from classpath

Comment: What environment are you running in (i.e. Java SE, OSGi, something on top of the Java VM, etc)?

Comment: Alert class looks like this:

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Alert", propOrder = {
    "alertId",
   
})
public class Alert
    implements Serializable{
    some fields
}

And i use Java Eclipse

Comment: Also when i import the project, from which my jar is generated, into my project then i am able to get JAXBContext.

Comment: Find a resolution to this? I have the same issue, but it works in Eclipse as a Junit test, but not when I run Ant Junit task. Obviously Eclipse is adding something to the classpath that I need, while Ant is not.

Comment: @user3174776 Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me as I had defined `XmlAdapter` implementations that were in a different JAR and not on the classpath. When trying to create the JAXBContext, it needs these adapters used by the JAXB type. Now that I figured this out, the message makes more sense, but is still very cryptic. `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is the annotation interface and the code fails to call the `value()` method of the annotation as it returns `Class<? extends XmlAdapter>`, a class type which is not defined on the classpath.

If you look at the code that throws the exception, this is impossible:

```
public Class More ...getClassValue(Annotation a, String name) {
  try {
    return (Class)a.annotationType().getMethod(name).invoke(a);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // impossible
    throw new IllegalAccessError(e.getMessage());
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // impossible
    throw new InternalError(e.getMessage());
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new NoSuchMethodError(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Would be nice if the cause of the exception was not lost.